# How does $2 \cos (\theta) - 1$ become $2 \left(1- 2\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)\right) -1$?

Tags: trigonometry

How does $$2 \cos (\theta) - 1 = 2 \left(1- 2\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)\right) -1$$
What property is this?

Comment: I think you are looking for $$\cos2\theta=1-2\sin^2\theta$$ instead.

Comment: @codelearner The identity you have written is false. I presume that after the due revision AndrewChin's comment will be the relevant tool.

Comment: @Gae. S. I think then the book I got it from is wrong. Sorry! thank you

Comment: Are you sure that the l.h.s. is not $2\cos^2\theta -1 $?

Comment: @Bernard I was actually referring to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis . I am not sure how they got sin from equation 6.

Comment: I forgot to divide the theta by 2. Does this help in anyway?

Comment: @codelearner Apply the first comment's equality with $\theta/2$ instead of $\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities), in the power-reduction formulae section:

> Obtained by solving the second and third versions of the cosine double-angle formula.  $\sin^2 \theta = \frac {1- \cos (2 \theta)}{2}$

And in the same page, in the multiple-angle formulae section:

> $\cos(2\theta)=\cos^2\theta - \sin^2 \theta = 1- 2 \sin^2 \theta$

And this can be proved using the angle sum identity for cosine: $\cos(\alpha + \beta) = \cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta$.

---

And with all that being said:
$$\require{cancel} 2 \cos (\theta) \cancel{- 1} = 2 \left(1- 2\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)\right) \cancel{-1}\\ \cancel{2} \cos (\theta) = \cancel{2} \left(1- 2\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)\right)
\\ \cos \left(2 \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right) = 1- 2\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)$$
Which is right according to the double angle formula.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Since $\cos 2 \theta = 1 - 2 \sin^2 \theta$, then $\cos \theta = 1 - 2 \sin^2 (\frac {\theta}{2})$.  Can you take it from here?